# Paramiko Emulating IBM 3151. How do I send the right control keypress

Tags: python, terminal, emulation, paramiko

I am using Python 2.7 Paramiko to SSH into a very old system that uses IBM 3151 keymapping.  Keyboards back then had an enter or "send" key used to submit responses.  In Secure NetTerm, I am able to access this system and the "send" key is mapped to the right ctrl key on the keyboard.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to send the "send" key to the terminal with Paramiko.  Below is my test code.  I am able to make it through the first few menu options which accept \n, but I am running into a "popup" screen that requires the "send" key.  Pressing the right ctrl key works in the emulator, but I can't seem to get anything to work in Paramiko.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import paramiko
import time

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    ssh.connect('some_server.com', port=22,username='some_user', password='some_password')
except paramiko.SSHException:
    print "Connection Failed"
    quit()
channel = ssh.invoke_shell(term='IBM-3151', width=80, height=24, width_pixels=0, height_pixels=0)
channel_data = str()
host = str()
srcfile = str()

while True:
    if channel.recv_ready():
        channel_data += channel.recv(9999)
    else:
        continue
    print channel_data
    #Go to store
    if channel_data.endswith('> '):# in channel_data:
        channel.send('5\n')
        # Select a store
    if channel_data.endswith(' : '):  # in channel_data:
        channel.send('0330\n')
    if channel_data.endswith('): '):  # in channel_data:
        channel.send('Y\n')
    if 'PRESS SEND TO CONTINUE....' in str(channel_data):
        print 'test1'  # if statement works
        time.sleep(5)
        channel.send('^[!l^M')  # tried all kinds of stuff here
        print 'test2'  # script passes to here with no errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd determine what characters are actually sent by the <kbd>*Send*</kbd> (or <kbd>*Enter*</kbd>) key by

- capture all of the characters from a session using `script` on the AIX system (you might need this for analysis)
- in a shell on the AIX system, use `cat` (to echo) and press *control*-V before pressing <kbd>*Enter</kbd>.

Do that with the working terminal of course.  If the data shown by `cat` does not work with your script, it's possible that there's some initialization done, e.g., putting Secure NetTerm into *application mode*.